# MySQL error 1064 connecting 3 tables query

Tags: java, mysql, join

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e FULL OUTER JOIN salarydetails s ON (e.Eid=s.Eid)
WHERE s.Month="January" AND e.Eid="0002"
UNION
SELECT *
FROM salarydetails s FULL OUTER JOIN bonus b ON (s.Eid=b.Eid)
WHERE b.Month="January" AND b.Eid="0002"
```

I have 3 tables: `employee`, `salarydetails`, and `bonus`. I’m writing a Java code to load a JTable. I have to get the data from these three tables. The query I’m trying to use is the above one. But it gives errors. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You can use `UNION` only if both queries result in the same number of columns of the same type in the same sequence.

Comment: is there any other way that i can use to do this? any relational algebra method or anything

Comment: If you describe what you are actually trying to achieve in enough detail, it's possible that I (or someone else) could suggest something.

Comment: I want to get the employee details in employee table, salary details in salarydetails table and bonus details from bonus table and load them to a jtable when the user enters employee ID and the month. I want to assign null for what ever the colomn that does not contain data when displaying on the table.I tried to get the data from 3 different ResultSet s and load them. but it only loads the table only if no null data is available. because of that, i wanted to use relational algebra to get tables with null values and display.

Comment: Post (add into your question by using *edit*) your schema, including primary and foreign keys.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do, preferably with sample data and desired results.  Your knowledge of MySQL is quite on the weak side, because MySQL does not support `full outer join`.